# What i can do for fix problem at result code(Cant add smth after surname add)?

Tags: c, clion

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct STUDENT{
    char Surname[50];
    char Name;
    char Patronymic;
    int Group;
    int Performance[5];
};

int main(){
    int Len;
    printf("Input amount of student's: ");
    scanf("%d",&Len);
    struct STUDENT info[Len];
    for(int i = 0; i < Len; i++){
        printf("Input Surname of student: ");
        scanf("%s", info[i].Surname);
        
        printf("Input Name of student: ");
        info[i].Name = getchar();

        printf("Input Patronymic of student: ");
        info[i].Patronymic = getchar();

        printf("Input Group of student: ");
        scanf("%d",&info[i].Group);

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            printf("Input Performance of student: ");
            info[i].Performance[j] = getchar();
        }
    }

    char SurSwap[50];
    char NameSwap;
    char PatronymicSwap;
    int GroupSwap;
    int PerformanceSwap[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < Len; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Len - 1; j++){
            if(info[j].Group < info[j + 1].Group){

                strcpy(SurSwap, info[j].Surname);
                strcpy(info[j].Surname, info[j + 1].Surname);
                strcpy(info[j + 1].Surname, SurSwap);

                NameSwap = info[j].Name;
                info[j].Name = info[j + 1].Name;
                info[j + 1].Name = NameSwap;

                PatronymicSwap = info[j].Patronymic;
                info[j].Patronymic = info[j + 1].Patronymic;
                info[j + 1]. Patronymic = PatronymicSwap;

                GroupSwap = info[j].Group;
                info[j].Group = info[j + 1].Group;
                info[j + 1].Group = GroupSwap;

                for(int q = 0; q < 5; q++){
                    PerformanceSwap[q] = info[j].Performance[q];
                    info[j].Performance[q] = info[j + 1].Performance[q];
                    info[j + 1].Performance[q] = PerformanceSwap[q];

                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nDatabase of student:\nSurname\tName\tPatronymic\tGroup\tPerformance");
    for(int i = 0; i < Len; i++){
        printf("\n%s", info[i].Surname);
        printf("\t%c", info[i].Name);
        printf("\t%c", info[i].Patronymic);
        printf("\t%d\t", info[i].Group);
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            printf("%d ", info[i].Performance[j]);
    }
}
```

My result: Input amount of student's: 3
Input Surname of student: solo
Input Name of student: Input Patronymic of student:

Dont know why this code are broken, after input surname - code are stoped.Help smth pls.I'm trying swaped type of Name to Arr, but have this problem too. As i know its 137 error; but i cant doing smth with this

Comment: What do you mean by *"it's 137 errors"*?

Comment: @Haris Guys, i know which getchar  read only one elem, but i dont know why i cant add smth after surname

Comment: @Haris  dont know, when i compiled this code at debug - i see 137 error; but i dont know what is it

Comment: Kindly edit the question to include the warnings and errors.

Comment: @Haris what u mean?*

Comment: @Haris check now

Comment: Did the compiler just say *"It's error 137*? Did it emit no warnings? Was there no text? What compiler are you using?  Moreover, you're missing the ```&``` operator during a call to ```scanf```. ```scanf``` leaves a newline character in the input buffer which gets automatically read by the call to ```getchar```, that's why you not being prompted for input.

Comment: @Haris try to use this code on comliler; I dont sure about 137 error; Im use Clion, and he dont see error's or warning's

Comment: @Haris and sry for my language, not mine main language

Comment: I'm not going to debug your code for you, you are. I already apprised you of the shortcomings in my last comment. Address them.

Comment: Unoiko, `info[i].Name = getchar();` just reads a _whitespace_. Not that useful.  The only thing in `stdin` after `scanf("%s", info[i].Surnam);` is whitespace.

Comment: @Haris yes, i fix them

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I know,  this info cant help me